# Is there a way to avoid fighting enemies in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have entered a cave and realized I'm too low level to complete it but I have gotten really far through and don't want to have to go back. Is there a way I can get through without having to attack everyone or take each person separately because I keep getting swarmed and dying. If the only way is pure luck or going back then I will but I was wondering if there was a way to get through. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for you, I found that most caves in Skyrim follow a pattern of a series of enemies/puzzles followed by a 'boss' to defeat at the end before exiting. That being said it is possible that the cave you are in will have an exit that is accessible without having to defeat the 'boss'. But even in that case you'll most likely have to sneak past them or make use of whatever potions you might have such as invisibility/sneak. So if your sneak is of a high enough level it might be worth trying to sneak past, but I'd say going back the way you came for now is your best bet.

I always found that making my way through caves using a combination of archery and sneaking was a good way to do a good bit of damage to a group of enemies before running in with my sword. Good use of shouts such as Fus Ro Dah are also invaluable when getting swarmed as they usually let you get a good couple of swings in while the enemy is knocked back or give you a chance to 're-group'.

Hope it helps!

Comment: If you're a Nord, don't forget your Battle Cry, either.